# Como funciona a herança de constructors em C#? Classe pai e filha(Base e derivada)

Tags: c#

Abaixo segue textos que estão em um livro que estive lendo para sanar algumas dúvidas minhas(Fiz alguns comentários para ver se fica mais compreensível), e no final irei colocar a minha pergunta(A qual irei revisar):

```
public class Conta //ESSA É A CLASSE PAI
{
                public int  Numero  {   get;    set;    }

//  Construtor  sem argumentos da classe pai:
                public  Conta() {}

// Construtor com argumentos da classe pai:
                public  Conta(int   numero)
                {
                                this.Numero =   numero;
                }
}

//EXEMPLO 01 - CONSTRUTOR NA CLASSE FILHA ABAIXO(ONDE COMEÇA MINHA DÚVIDA): 

public class ContaPoupanca  :   Conta
{

/*  Abaixo estamos  chamando    o   construtor  da  classe  pai que já  faz a 
atribuição do   número  e   por isso    o   corpo   
do  construtor  pode    ficar   vazio: */

                public  ContaPoupanca(int   numero) :   base    (numero) {  }
}
```

> Dentro do  C#, sempre  que construímos uma instância   de      ContaPoupanca   ,   o   C#  sempre
> precisa chamar  um  construtor  da  classe      Conta       para     fazer  a   inicialização   da  classe  base( ~ ESSA PARTE EU NÃO ENTENDO, MAS ESTÁ NO LIVRO ~ ).
> Quando  não
> invocamos   explicitamente  o   construtor  da  classe  pai,    o   C#  coloca  implicitamente  uma chamada para    o
> construtor  sem argumentos  da  classe  pai( ~ Também não entendo essa parte, mas também está no livro ~ ):

```
EXEMPLO 02 - CONSTRUTOR NA CLASSE FILHA(ESSA É A PARTE QUE ME DEIXOU DÚVIDAS): 

public class ContaPoupanca  :   Conta
{
//Nesse código  o   C#  chamará o   construtor  sem argumentos  
//da    classe  Conta(E caso o mesmo não exista irá resultar em erro)

                public  ContaPoupanca(int   numero)
                {
                                this.Numero =   numero;
                }
}
```

> Se a   classe      Conta       não definir o   construtor  sem argumentos, temos   um  erro    de  compilação  se  não
> invocarmos  explicitamente  um  construtor  da  classe  pai.

Minha dúvida: Bom, essa última parte(Código acima) que não entendo o pq do erro, mesmo que tenha sido dito que foi pelo simples fato de não existir na classe pai um construtor padrão.

No livro diz: "nesse   código  o   C#  chamará o   construtor  sem argumentos  da  classe  Conta, e caso o mesmo não exista irá resultar em erro.", mas não entendo pq será chamado o construtor sem argumentos da classe Conta, uma vez que o mesmo não está sendo chamado quando fazemos na classe filha:

```
public  ContaPoupanca(int   numero)
                {
this.Numero =   numero;
                }
}
```

Ou está sim sendo chamado o construtor padrão(Sem argumentos) da classe pai no construtor acima? Pois, pelo que tentei, não consigo utilizar o código citado acima sem que haja na classe pai um construtor padrão(Mas afinal, se estou na classe filha ainda estou preso ao construtor pai? E pq tem necessariamente que haver o construtor padrão na classe pai para que o código acima seja compilado sem erro?)

**Sendo breve, em resumo, a minha principal dúvida a seguir:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tudo bem então...

Comment: Tem razão... Acho que deixei ela mais clara e objetiva agora.

Comment: Realmente, tem todo sentido. Título editado... Agora creio estar bem mais atrativo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que você esta fazendo é um acesso a variável **idade** da classe pai por estar pública, não tem necessidade de declarar um construtor, poderia tranquilamente ser implementada desta forma.

```
public class Conta
{
    public int Numero { get; set; }

    public int Idade { get; set; }
}

public class ContaPoupanca : Conta
{
    public ContaPoupanca(int idade)
    {
        Idade = idade;
    }
}
```

Mas se você utilizar um parâmetro no construtor da classe **Conta**(pai) é necessário passar ele como referência na classe **ContaPoupanca**(Filha) utilizando a referência de **base**:

```
public class Conta
{
    public int Numero { get; set; }

    public int Idade { get; set; }

    public Conta(int idade)
    {
        Idade = idade;
    }
}

public class ContaPoupanca : Conta
{
    public ContaPoupanca(int idade) : base(idade)
    {
        
    }
}
```

Outra opção é colocar as propriedade de pai como **public readonly**, fazendo com que as atribuições sejam feitas apenas no construtor, como no exemplo abaixo. Assim existe a garantia da imutabilidade dos valores, pois seriam apenas de leitura.

```
public class Conta
{
    public readonly int Numero;

    public readonly int Idade;

    public Conta(int numero, int idade)
    {
        Numero = numero;
        Idade = idade;
    }
}

public class ContaPoupanca : Conta
{
    public ContaPoupanca(int numero, int idade) : base(numero, idade)
    {
    }
}
```

Se quiser se aprofundar mais, sugiro essa documentação sobre como usar construtores -> https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-constructors